# HTML5 translate method, how to reset to default?

Tags: html, canvas

Since HTML5's translate-method moves the origin of drawing relatively to its former origin apparently. (when I use ctx.translate(20,20) twice in a row I get the same result as when I use ctx.translate(40,40))
Well now the problem is I'd like to reset the origin of drawing to its original position(the position it had before first useing of translate() on it), how do I do that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

[MDN setTransform documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5);` and never worry about resetting transformation.

Comment: Although this works, @Loktar answer should be accepted as the best one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11144306/1866876

Comment: If all you want is to undo a single batch of translations back to default (untransformed) space, then `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` is better than `save & restore` because save/restore works on every context property instead of just the transformations.

Comment: indeed, this was the answer I needed too (I already knew about the save/restore and it wasn't what I was looking for)

Answer (score 66):

You can do that by using `.save()` and `.restore()`

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(// do some translations);
// draw whatever
ctx.restore();
```

You need to call `save()` to "save" the current contexts state. Then you can perform translations, rotations, etc. After your finished call `restore()` to reset the context's state to what it was when you initially called `save()`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaZak/)**

[MDN Tutorial also explaining it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas)

Comment: This is the best solution because it allows you to stack transformations.

Answer (score 7):

```
ctx.resetTransform();
```

See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform) for more info. It has very low browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to reset the default of the `translate` operation, which is a subset of all the solutions proposed above.

Whether you apply `save/reset`, `setTransform` or `resetTransform`, you'll reset values not only for the translation but also for skewing and scaling (and even style, in the case of the first).

To **only** undo translations, we need to only restore 2 of the 6 properties of the transform matrix Canvas uses, leaving the rest unchanged:

```js
const currentTransform = ctx.getTransform();

// Properties deconstructed for illustrative purposes:
const hScale = currentTransform.m11;
const vSkew = currentTransform.m12;
const hSkew = currentTransform.m21;
const vScale = currentTransform.m22;
const hTranslation = currentTransform.dx;
const vTranslation = currentTransform.dy;

ctx.setTransform(hScale, vSkew, hSkew, vScale, 0, 0);
```

This will reset translation to the origin (0, 0) without altering any scale or skewing.

---

*Note that this could also be achieved by using `transform(...)` and defining a transformation matrix to be multiplied by the one canvas is currently holding, again altering translation and keeping scale and skew as they are. However, writing such a matrix would require knowing the amount by which we are currently offset from the origin, and knowing this information would allow us to just apply `translate` with negative values in the first place.*