# Ease in/out camera movement for canvas

Tags: javascript

I have a function which moves a camera to a position that the user clicks on the canvas. But currently the movement is linear. I would like it to use an ease in/out transition but am having difficulty understanding how to implement it with my current function.

This is the code I have:

```
animate.mouseEvent = function(e,el){        
    var mousePos = mouse.relativePosition(e,el);
    var parent   = el;
    if(e.button == 0){

            function update(){
                if(centerX == mousePos.x && centerY == mousePos.y){
                    clearInterval(parent.timer);
                    //center X / Y is canvas width & height halved
                }

                var difx            = centerX - mousePos.x,
                    dify            = centerY - mousePos.y,
                    distance        = Math.sqrt(difx*difx + dify*dify),
                    normalX         = difx/distance,
                    normalY         = dify/distance,
                    speed           = 1, //currently linear [replace with ease in/out]
                    x               = normalX * speed,
                    y               = normalY * speed;

                    updateOffsets(x,y);                     
                    mousePos.x  += x;
                    mousePos.y  += y;
                }
                parent.timer = setInterval(update,1);   
     }
}


animate.updateOffsets = function(x,y){
    canvas.offsetX -= x;
    canvas.offsetY -= y;
}
```

So i was wondering how i would implement an ease in/out from my current linear method. Using the below function:

```
Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d/2;
    if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    t--;
    return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
};
```

I don't fully know how to implement it or what exactly it would be returning for me to calculate the new offset with. Was hoping some one could explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea. I used another easing function, you can substitute your own. [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbWbOp)

```
var element = document.getElementById('moving');
var bg = document.getElementById('background');

bg.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  animate({
    x: evt.offsetX,
    y: evt.offsetY
  });
}, false);

function getPosition() {
  return {
    x: element.offsetLeft,
    y: element.offsetTop
  };
}
function setPosition(x, y) {
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
}

function easing(x) {
  return 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin((x - 0.5) * Math.PI);
}

function animate(target) {
  var initial = getPosition();
  var initialX = initial.x;
  var initialY = initial.y;
  var targetX = target.x;
  var targetY = target.y;
  var deltaX = targetX - initialX;
  var deltaY = targetY - initialY;

  var timeStart = timestamp();
  var timeLength = 800;

  var timer = setInterval(update, 10);

  function timestamp() {
    return Date.now();
  }
  function stop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  function update() {
    var t = (timestamp() - timeStart) / timeLength;
    if (t > 1) {
      fraction(1);
      stop();
    } else {
      fraction(easing(t));
    }
  }
  function fraction(t) {
    setPosition(initialX + t * deltaX, initialY + t * deltaY);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Applied to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1v7pe3r/3/) you provided:

```
var element         = document.getElementById('background');
var ctx             = element.getContext("2d");
var camera          = {};
    // camera.offset marks the position seen at the upper left corner
    // (It would be better if it marked the center)
    // Let these be negative, so (0,0) scene position is at the center of the image
    camera.offsetX  = -element.width/2;
    camera.offsetY  = -element.height/2;
var obj             = {};
    obj.x           = 50;
    obj.y           = 50;

element.addEventListener('click', animate, false);

function easing(x) {
      return 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin((x - 0.5) * Math.PI);
}

function animate(evt){
    // Transform click position from screen coordinates to scene coordinates
  var targetX       = evt.offsetX + camera.offsetX - element.width / 2,
      targetY       = evt.offsetY + camera.offsetY - element.height / 2;

  var initialX      = camera.offsetX,
    initialY        = camera.offsetY;

  var deltaX        = targetX - initialX,
      deltaY        = targetY - initialY;

  var timeStart     = Date.now();
  var timeLength    = 800;
  var timer         = setInterval(update, 10);

  function stop(){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }

  function update(){
    var t = (Date.now() - timeStart) / timeLength;
      if (t > 1) {
          fraction(1);
          stop();
      } else {
          fraction(easing(t));
      }
  }    
  function fraction(t){
      camera.offsetX = initialX + t * deltaX,
      camera.offsetY = initialY + t * deltaY;
  }
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,element.width,element.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect((element.width/2)-2,(element.height/2)-2,4,4);       

    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    // ===> Here the size and position arguments were swapped
  ctx.fillRect(obj.x-camera.offsetX,obj.y-camera.offsetY, 20, 20);   
}

// Consider using requestAnimationFrame
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Comment: does this use a ease in/out ?

Comment: Yes, it certanly does, a sine-like easing, a bit hard to notice. Handling the coordinates of the box is not accurate. The easing function should be a function with `easing(0)=0 and easing(1)=1`, and will be smooth if `easing'(0)=easing'(1)=0` (derivative is zero at 0 and 1) Try and fiddle around with the easing fn

Comment: i tried to implement this method for moving a camera here: http://jsfiddle.net/b1v7pe3r/ but i cannot get it to work for some reason. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: It was mainly wrong because you swapped the parameters of fillRect at the blue thing, and drew a rect with -250 width. See my edit

Comment: why i was fiddling around with this code and made this: http://jsfiddle.net/hsrvh0L2/ I changed how the camera works so it refers the middle of the screen rather than the top left, sadly though now the animation is broken and i could not work out why or how to solve it.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/b1v7pe3r/4/ It's better to use the middle of the screen as the camera offset, but that introduces a new coordinate system. (we now have world, camera, and screen cordinates, previously the camera and screen coordinates were the same.) This means we have to transform back when drawing (-w/2, -h/2)

Comment: Edited your version too, and added some comments: http://jsfiddle.net/hsrvh0L2/1/

Comment: What does the line  `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);` do?

Comment: Clears the transformation, so you don't have to translate it back. Translating and translating back in every frame will cause cumulated erors after a time. Other option would be `ctx.save(); ...; ctx.restore();`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144193/html5-translate-method-how-to-reset-to-default

Comment: Hmm i wonder which one is better performance over all. Save and restore seems to be simpler to remember.

Comment: ctx.setTransform is certanly better at performance, bevause save and restore stores other states too, for example paint color or line width. In my opinion save and restore is to draw object hierarchies, and setTransform is to reset the state.

Comment: Hmm i found this: http://jsperf.com/canvas-transform-vs-save-restore/8 seems for me save restore was faster. I suspect it uses more memory if it stores more data though, but as far as time taken it seems faster =/

Comment: In my browser this benchmark ended in exactly the same result :D It's up to you. If you use save/restore, you have to watch out for exceptions. Make sure you always restore the state.