# Javascript animation easing

Tags: javascript, animation, math, canvas, easing

I have a function which moves my canvas using an ease in aspect. The problem how ever is the canvas animation doesn't work. It just scrolls too far and what appears to be too fast as well.

This is my function which moves the camera to the location the user clicked on the canvas:

```
function moveCamera(e,parent){
    clearInterval(parent.scroll);

var mouseData       = mousePos(evt,parent); //get x:y relative to element           
var initial         = {'x':el.width/2,'y':el.height/2},
    target          = {'x':mouseData.x,'y':mouseData.y},            
    deltaX          = target.x-initial.x,
    deltaY          = target.y-initial.y,
    timeStart       = Date.now(),
    timeLength      = 800,
    x,y,deltaTime;

function update(){
    function fraction(t){
        x               = (target.x - initial.x) - (t*deltaX),
        y               = (target.y - initial.y) - (t*deltaY);
        camera.x       -= x;
        camera.y       -= y;
    }
    function easing(x) {
        return 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin((x - 0.5) * Math.PI);
    }   

    deltaTime = (Date.now() - timeStart) / timeLength;
    if (deltaTime > 1) {
        fraction(1);
    } else {
        fraction(easing(deltaTime));
    }   
}
parent.scroll = setInterval(update, 10);        
}
```

I have attatched a JSFiddle of the issue demonstrated: **http://jsfiddle.net/p5xjmLay/** simply click on the canvas to scroll to that position, and you will see it goes a bit crazy.

I am wondering how to solve this so the camera offset changes correctly each time?

Comment: Isn't it the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600794/ease-in-out-camera-movement-for-canvas ?

Comment: @Kaiido it is an earlier version of it when i had a different setup. That did work but it used to set the camera position to its location where as i want to get the difference and update the camera offset each loop instead. Also as you can see in the jsFiddle, it doesn't actually work since the changes and am unsure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a little bit your version and it seems that it is working, please try this:

```
    var el      = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    initial         = {'x':el.width/2,'y':el.height/2},
    ctx     = el.getContext('2d'),
    camera  = {'x':el.width/2,'y':el.height/2},
    box     = {'x':0,'y':0};
    var x,y,deltaTime;

    el.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){moveCamera(e,this);},false);

function moveCamera(e,parent){
        clearInterval(parent.scroll);

    var mouseData       = mousePos(e,parent);                       
        target          = {'x':mouseData.x,'y':mouseData.y},            
        deltaX          = target.x-initial.x,
        deltaY          = target.y-initial.y,
        timeStart       = Date.now(),
        timeLength      = 800;


    function update(){
        function fraction(t){
            x               = target.x - (initial.x + (t*deltaX)),
            y               = target.y - (initial.y + (t*deltaY));

            if (Math.abs(camera.x + x - target.x) > Math.abs(camera.x - target.x)) {
                camera.x = target.x;
                initial.x = target.x;
            } else {
                camera.x       += x;                
            }

            if (Math.abs(camera.y + y - target.y) > Math.abs(camera.y - target.y)) {
                camera.y = target.y;
                initial.y = target.y;
            } else {
                camera.y       += y;                
            }            

        }
        function easing(x) {
            return 0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin((x - 0.5) * Math.PI);
        }   

        deltaTime = (Date.now() - timeStart) / timeLength;
        if (deltaTime > 1) {
            fraction(1);
        } else {
            fraction(easing(deltaTime));
        }
        draw(); 
    }
    parent.scroll = setInterval(update, 200);       
}

function mousePos(evt,el){
        var offsetX = 0,
            offsetY = 0;        
        do{
            offsetX += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
            offsetY += el.offsetTop  - el.scrollTop;
        }while(el = el.offsetParent){
            return {'x':evt.pageX - offsetX, 'y':evt.pageY - offsetY}       
        }       
}

function draw(){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,el.width,el.height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(camera.x,camera.y);     

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(box.x-25, box.y-25,50,50);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill(); 

    ctx.restore();           
}
draw();
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of what you changed so I understand where I went wrong

Comment: Basically, I applied 3 things:
1) Fix the increment for camera.x and camera.y, in the fraction function you had "camera.x -= x" (and the same for camera.y) and I realized that the canvas was going away instead of going near, that's why I changed the expression by "camera.x += x".

Comment: 2) When I fixed the increment for camera.x I realized that the canvas was continue going forward even when the target was reached, then I added the condition to see if the difference between "camera.x + x" and " target.x" is greater than "camera.x - target.x", if yes, this means that if I assign "camera.x += x" I will pass the target, then I assigned the value of target "camera.x = target.x" (the same for camera.y)

Comment: 3) When I have reached the target is time to update the initial coordinates of the canvas in order to allow continue with the next clic starting from the current position: "initial.x = target.x" (and the same for initial.y).

I hope I have given to you a good explanation, greetings.

Comment: For me this just moves the box at lightning speed, im not seeing an easing animation that takes 800 milliseconds..so i would say it doesn't really work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmcfvr9t/ - your answer doesn't utilise `t` which is passed to function `fraction`

Comment: Ofcourse the version I wrote uses "t", see: "x               = (target.x - initial.x) - (**t***deltaX)". I have given you a hint. It is up to you to modify your increments to get the animation you want, greetings.