# How can I change size of context depending on which option is selected on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scaling

I'm working on a game where the size of the fish(or whatever item they choose) is dependent on which option the user selects from a drop down menu. e.g. if they select small, the fish will get smaller etc. and when they select a different size, the fish that they draw on the canvas will change as well. I've tried scaling and changing the size within the draw function, but each time, I've come against a problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Example of one of my shapes

```
function triangle(params){
this.ctx = (typeof params.ctx !== "undefined") ? params.ctx : null;

this.x = (typeof params.x !== "undefined") ? params.x : 0;
this.y = (typeof params.y !== "undefined") ? params.y : 0;
this.width = (typeof params.width !== "undefined") ? params.width : 100;
this.height = (typeof params.height !== "undefined") ? params.height : 50;

this.strokeColour = (typeof params.strokeColour !== "undefined") ? params.strokeColour : "red";
this.strokeWidth = (typeof params.strokeWidth !== "undefined") ? params.strokeWidth : 2;
this.fillColour = (typeof params.fillColour !== "undefined") ? params.fillColour : "green";

this.draw = function(){


    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeColour;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = this.strokeWidth;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColour;

    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(this.x - 34, this.y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.x + 0, this.y - 54);
    this.ctx.lineTo(this.x + 40, this.y);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.stroke();


}
```

}

What I have tried so far

```
if(fishSize.selectedIndex == 0){

            ctx.scale(0.5,0.5);
            ctx.scale(1,1);

        } else if(fishSize.selectedIndex == 1){
            ctx.scale(1,1);
        } else {
            ctx.scale(1,1.5);
        }
```

Comment: Okay, Okay sorry, code is on it's way!

Comment: @markE - Code has now been added above

Comment: Usually when you "come against a problem", you'll need to "find a solution".

Best I can do with the vagueness of the question. But really, what's happening that you don't expect?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris - Basically when a user selects an option from my drop down menu(either small, medium or large) i want the size of the selected fish to also change size so that when they click on the canvas, the shape of the fish will also change size depending on what size has been selected. At the moment, the shape is scaling down each time I click the canvas, but really I only want the shape to change size once, so there's a default size for small shape,medium shape and large shape instead of the shape, getting bigger or smaller each time I click the canvas.

Comment: `scale` applies a scaling transformation to the projection matrix of the underlying draw calls. So, you'll need to adjust the scaling *before* those draw calls are made. If you need to adjust the scaling after the draw calls are made, you'll need to clear and redraw the entire scene. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale

Comment: Think of it like using a camera. If you take a picture, and then change the lens, the picture you just took doesn't change. You'll need to re-take the picture.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Okay I see what you mean but how exactly can I adjust scaling of the context before it is called?

Comment: you call the same *scale* method you've been calling. Se the link I mentioned above for the "official" API documentation.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris - Yes I have and Iv'e followed the link, Iv'e called the function before it is drawn so it changes size when the user clicks first time. The problem that I'm still having is that the shape continues to scale up or down when the user keeps clicking. I just want it to stay at the same size.

Comment: Ah, yes. Calling scale has a multiplicative effect on the underlying projection matrix. You'll also need to manually set the matrix to an identity matrix before re-drawing the scene. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144193/html5-translate-method-how-to-reset-to-default